# How to specify the TGT kerberos ticket cache in beeline

Tags: apache, jdbc, hive, kerberos

I have this scenario where I want to make hive jdbc connections using multiple users/principals. I can get multiple KERBEROS tickets and store them in different cache files. For example one could be in /tmp/ticket1 and the other in /tmp/ticket2. However, when I execute the beeline how do I specify which ticket to use. I want to run queries as different users.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can't. The whole Hadoop ecosystem assumes that you use a ticket cache in the default location - even legitimate KRB5 environment variables are ignored (or just mess with some hardcoded defaults somewhere).

On my current assignment I had to develop a crude "Beeline emulator" in plain Java to handle that issue. It took me weeks to troubleshoot the KRB and the GSS configuration issues, including weird syntax inconsistencies between various versions of OpenJDK and Sun JRE (plus Linux vs. Windows), but finally I got it working.

And no, I will never share it with anyone outside of my Big Corp client with Big Lawyer staff...